# Fix or clean git in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, push

I pushed a commit to the server from Android Studio,
The push succeeded and I could see my commits on Bitbucket site.

When I return to Android Studio and try to push again (without any changes!),
I'm getting the popup window with the same commits that I pushed already.

It's like the Android Studio is not remembering it.
(He does remember the commits and shows my: "Nothing to commit")

It's an Android Studio issue, because in SourceTree / Command Line it's fine.

Comment: Open the terminal in Android Studio and write `git status` or use the refresh icon in VCS view, should be a plug-in refresh issue. If doesn't work restart Android studio.

Comment: can't reproduce on AS3 beta4

Comment: @lubilis git status returns: "nothing to commit, working tree clean" It didn't help, still have the problem

Comment: Git is working, it's only a plug-in bug probably. Try to unregister Git root in Settings | Version Control and register it again to force refresh. Or pull from remote repository / make another commit and push it